# FFMPEG not copying over metadata GPS data

Tags: ffmpeg

Recording device tags the video file with geolocation, when converting from mov to mp4 the geolocation data is missing.
`ffmpeg -i source.mov -r 60 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -map_metadata -1 -movflags faststart destination.mp4`

Am I doing something wrong? I'm running the command from Windows 10 x64. If it's not possible, is there a way to use a command at the same time for ExifTool to write it?

The lines for metadata missing:
`com.apple.quicktime.location.I` &
`©xyz`

Comment: Should be `-map_metadata 0`. `-1` means to not copy metadata. May not still work but try.

Comment: That didn't help; the lines missing: 
`com.apple.quicktime.location.I` &
`©xyz `

Comment: Look like you have to use [Bento4](https://www.bento4.com/downloads/). See http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=7826.msg41363#msg41363

Comment: Related to FFmpeg tickets [#4209](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4209) and [#6193](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6193).

Comment: Is there any fix to this please?